# Invalided a signed in Firebase user that was signed in with a custom token

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

We're using [Firebase Custom Auth](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/custom-auth) to sign users in on mobile clients with a custom token that is generated from a different micro-service per the instructions [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/create-custom-tokens).

This is done on in the micro-service:

```
String uid = "some-uid";

String customToken = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().createCustomToken(uid);
// Send token back to client
```

And then on the mobile client we sign in with that custom token:

```
// iOS Mobile Client
Auth.auth().signIn(withCustomToken: customToken ?? "") { user, error in
  // ...
}
```

After signing in, the mobile client now has a refresh token it uses to authenticate itself.

If the user's account was compromised or their password changed in the micro-service, the documentation shows this method to revoke refresh tokens:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().revokeRefreshTokens(uid);
```

My question is: How do I correctly invalidate a signed in user and re-authenticate them?

I was thinking of doing this:

1. Revoke their refresh tokens on the backend
2. Create a new custom token on the backend and send to client
3. Sign them out on the mobile client
4. Sign them in again with the new custom token

Is this the right way to do it? Or am I missing something?